# Swipe events work on Chrome for iphone but not for android/chrome dev tools

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, swipe

I've written custom swipe events based off the Google tutorial for this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/touch/

The design involves two swipable drawers, one that comes down from the top, the other up from the bottom. The swiping behaviour works just fine in Firefox, Chrome (when not in responsive design mode) and Safari. It also works on iPhone.

However, it **doesn't** work when I switch to responsive design mode in Chrome, nor does it seem to work on Chrome on Android. The touchstart, touchmove and touchend events are all firing correctly, but something on Android and Chrome (in RD mode) seems to be pre-emptively stopping or cancelling the swipe gestures. I've tried debugging but nothing appears to be working, and Googling isn't bringing up anything either.

The position property refers to whether it's the top drawer being accessed or not.

Here's the code:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
            function( callback ){
              window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
  })();


// ^ Check for pointer events support...

var pointerDownName = "pointerdown";
var pointerUpName = "pointerup";
var pointerMoveName = "pointermove";

if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
  pointerDownName = "MSPointerDown";
  pointerUpName = "MSPointerUp";
  pointerMoveName = "MSPointerMove";
}

// Simple way to check if some form of pointerevents is enabled or not
window.PointerEventsSupport = false;
if (window.PointerEvent || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
  window.PointerEventsSupport = true;
}

class Swiper {
  constructor(element, position, otherSwiper, search) {
    this.search = search;
    this.element = element;
    this.position = position;
    this.otherSwiper = otherSwiper;

    this.IN_STATE = 1;
    this.OUT_STATE = 2;
    this.differenceInY = 0;
    this.rafPending = false;
    //   * where the touch happens
    this.initialTouchPos = null;
    // * where the last touch happened
    this.lastTouchPos = null;
    this.open = true;
    this.scrollThreshold;
    this.itemHeight = element.offsetHeight;

    if (this.position === "top") {
      this.inTransformVal = -(element.offsetHeight * 0.85);
      this.outTransformVal = -(element.offsetHeight * 0.08);
      this.OTHER_ONE_inTransformVal = element.offsetHeight * 0.85;
      this.OTHER_ONE_outTransformVal = element.offsetHeight * 0.08;
    } else {
      this.inTransformVal = element.offsetHeight * 0.85;
      this.outTransformVal = element.offsetHeight * 0.08;
      this.OTHER_ONE_inTransformVal = -(element.offsetHeight * 0.85);
      this.OTHER_ONE_outTransformVal = -(element.offsetHeight * 0.08);
    }

    if (this.position == "top"){
        this.inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".drawer__jp__input");
    }

    this.startTransform = this.inTransformVal;

    //   * where the bottom of the div is currently located
    // * the transform value is -(500 - currentYPosition)

    this.currentState = this.IN_STATE;

    // Perform client width here as this can be expensive and doens't
    // change until window.onresize

    // *   the height of the div
    this.slopValue = this.itemHeight * (1 / 4);

    this.handleGestureStart = this.handleGestureStart.bind(this);
    this.handleGestureMove = this.handleGestureMove.bind(this);
    this.handleGestureEnd = this.handleGestureEnd.bind(this);
    this.updateSwipeRestPosition = this.updateSwipeRestPosition.bind(this);
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    this.getGesturePointFromEvent = this.getGesturePointFromEvent.bind(this);
    this.addListeners = this.addListeners.bind(this);
    this.onAnimFrame = this.onAnimFrame.bind(this);
    this.addListeners();
  }

  handleGestureStart(evt) {



    if (this.otherSwiper.currentState !== this.otherSwiper.IN_STATE) {
      this.otherSwiper.changeState(this.otherSwiper.IN_STATE);
    }

    if (evt.touches && evt.touches.length > 1) {
      return;
    }

    // Add the move and end listeners
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      evt.target.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId);

    } else {
      // Add Mouse Listeners
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleGestureMove, true);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleGestureEnd, true);
    }

    this.initialTouchPos = this.getGesturePointFromEvent(evt);
    this.element.style.transition = "initial";
  }

  handleGestureMove(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    if (!this.initialTouchPos) {
      return;
    }

    this.lastTouchPos = this.getGesturePointFromEvent(evt);

    if (this.rafPending) {
      return;
    }

    this.rafPending = true;

    window.requestAnimFrame(this.onAnimFrame);
  }

  handleGestureEnd(evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();


    if (evt.touches && evt.touches.length > 0) {
      return;
    }

    this.rafPending = false;

    // Remove Event Listeners
    if (window.PointerEvent) {
      evt.target.releasePointerCapture(evt.pointerId);
    } else {
      // Remove Mouse Listeners
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleGestureMove, true);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.handleGestureEnd, true);
    }

    this.updateSwipeRestPosition();

    this.initialTouchPos = null;
  }

  updateSwipeRestPosition() {

    let differenceInY = this.initialTouchPos.y - this.lastTouchPos.y;
    let currentTransform = this.startTransform - differenceInY;
    let newState = this.currentState;

    if (Math.abs(differenceInY) > this.slopValue) {
      if (this.currentState === this.IN_STATE) {
        if (this.position === "top") {
          if (differenceInY > 0) {
            newState = this.IN_STATE;
          } else {
            newState = this.OUT_STATE;
          }
        } else {
          if (differenceInY < 0) {
            newState = this.IN_STATE;
          } else {
            newState = this.OUT_STATE;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.position === "top") {
          if (this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE && differenceInY > 0) {
            newState = this.IN_STATE;
          } else if (
            this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE &&
            differenceInY < 0
          ) {
            newState = this.OUT_STATE;
          }
        } else {
          if (this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE && differenceInY < 0) {
            newState = this.IN_STATE;
          } else if (
            this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE &&
            differenceInY > 0
          ) {
            newState = this.OUT_STATE;
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      newState = this.currentState;
    }

    this.element.style.transition = "all 150ms ease-out";
    this.changeState(newState);
  }

  changeState(newState) {


    let transformStyle;
    switch (newState) {
      case this.IN_STATE:
        this.startTransform = this.inTransformVal;
        if (this.position === "top"){
            this.inputs.forEach(input => {
                input.style.opacity = 0;
            })
        }
        break;
      case this.OUT_STATE:
        this.startTransform = this.outTransformVal;
        if (this.position === "top"){
            this.inputs.forEach(input => {
                input.style.opacity = 1;
            })
        }
        break;
    }

    this.transformStyle =
      "translateY(" + this.startTransform + "px) translateX(-50%)";

    this.element.style.msTransform = this.transformStyle;
    this.element.style.MozTransform = this.transformStyle;
    this.element.style.webkitTransform = this.transformStyle;
    this.element.style.transform = this.transformStyle;

    this.currentState = newState;

    if (this.position === "top" && this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE){
        Swiper.underline.classList.add("open")
      } else {
          Swiper.underline.classList.remove("open")
      }
  }

  getGesturePointFromEvent(evt) {

    var point = {};

    if (evt.targetTouches) {
      point.x = evt.targetTouches[0].clientX;
      point.y = evt.targetTouches[0].clientY;
    } else {
      // Either Mouse event or Pointer Event
      point.x = evt.clientX;
      point.y = evt.clientY;
    }


    return point;
  }

  onAnimFrame() {

    if (!this.rafPending) {
      return;
    }

    let differenceInY = this.initialTouchPos.y - this.lastTouchPos.y;

    let newYTransform = this.startTransform - differenceInY;
    let transformStyle;


    if (this.position === "top") {
      if (newYTransform < -5) {
        transformStyle = `translateY(${newYTransform}px) translateX(-50%)`;
        if (this.currentState === this.OUT_STATE) {
            this.inputs.forEach(input => {
                input.style.opacity = 1 - (differenceInY / 100);
            })
        } 
      }
    } 
    else {
      if (newYTransform > 5) {
        transformStyle = `translateY(${newYTransform}px) translateX(-50%)`;
      }
    }

    this.element.style.webkitTransform = transformStyle;
    this.element.style.MozTransform = transformStyle;
    this.element.style.msTransform = transformStyle;
    this.element.style.webkitTransform = transformStyle;
    this.element.style.transform = transformStyle;

    this.rafPending = false;
  }

  addListeners() {

    if (window.PointerEvent) {

      // Add Pointer Event Listener
      this.element.addEventListener(
        "pointerdown",
        this.handleGestureStart,
        true
      );
      this.element.addEventListener(
        "pointermove",
        this.handleGestureMove,
        true
      );
      this.element.addEventListener("pointerup", this.handleGestureEnd, true);
      this.element.addEventListener(
        "pointercancel",
        this.handleGestureEnd,
        true
      );
    } 
    else {
      // Add Touch Listener
      this.element.addEventListener(
        "touchstart",
        this.handleGestureStart,
        true
      );
      this.element.addEventListener("touchmove", this.handleGestureMove, true);
      this.element.addEventListener("touchend", this.handleGestureEnd, true);
      this.element.addEventListener("touchcancel", this.handleGestureEnd, true);

      // Add Mouse Listener
      this.element.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleGestureStart, true);

    }

    // if (this.search) {
    //     this.search.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    //         if (this.currentState === this.IN_STATE){
    //             this.changeState(this.OUT_STATE)
    //         }
    //     }, true)
    // }

  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {


  setTimeout(() => {
    var h = Math.max(
      document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      window.innerHeight || 0
    );

    const main = document.querySelector(".main");





    window.onresize = function() {
        main.setAttribute("style",`height:${h}px`);
    };

    Swiper.underline = document.querySelector('.jp__header__underline');

    window.onresize();

    const topDrawer = document.querySelector(".drawer__container--top");
    const bottomDrawer = document.querySelector(".drawer__container--bottom");


    const search = document.querySelector(".drawer__search__form");
    const bottomSwiper = new Swiper(bottomDrawer, "bottom", null, search);
    const topSwiper = new Swiper(topDrawer, "top", bottomSwiper, null);
    bottomSwiper.otherSwiper = topSwiper;


    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".searchbar-input")

    const map = document.querySelector(".map__container")
    const searchInput = document.querySelector(".drawer__search__input");

    map.addEventListener("click", () => {
        bottomSwiper.changeState(bottomSwiper.IN_STATE)
        topSwiper.changeState(topSwiper.IN_STATE)
        searchInput.value = "";

    })

  }, 500);
});
```

It would be great to know if anyone else has had a similar issue...

Comment: If you think you've found an actual bug: http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: Thanks Morrison, I think I will